# Editing relationships between two tables

Tags: database, crud, user-experience

I have a table which have composite primary keys consisting of columns kin and child (each of which is foreign key for two other tables, but now I am not about these tables) and also a column of the type ENUM('mother','father','grandmother','grandfather','ant','uncle') and an ENUM('false','true') column specifying whether the adult can take the child from the kindergarten.

What is the proper way to edit this table through a Web interface?

The normal CRUD would not work here, because CRUD either creates a new table row with a newly generated primary key, or updates an existing row preserving its primary key unchanged. Here we however have the primary key as a part of edited data.

Or maybe, should I introduce a new integer column and make it the primary key (switching the kin+child key to be just UNIQUE instead of PRIMARY)?

What should be the HTML forms to edit this data? What is the best way to edit this data?

My question is not about how to implement this, but what should be the (HTML) interface: Which exactly field should the editing form have, what exactly should happen on form submit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for adding a new column and making that the primary key, and making kin+child a unique index. That way your html form can have all the controls in;

- Choose a kin
- Choose a child
- Choose a relationship
- Choose whether they can be collected
- Save as a new entry in the table

Nothing different to your usual CRUD needs to happen.